# failover option throws error in mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-connector-python

This is my code:

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
        'user': 'bb123',\
        'password': 'tt',\
        'host': 'adb',\
        'failover': 'bdb',\
        }

 self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(**self.config)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
return _get_failover_connection(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 109, in _get_failover_connection
    diff = set(server.keys()) - support_cnx_args
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

How do I enable the failover database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `failover` value should be a list or a tuple of dictionaries that contain the connection details for the failover server. E.g.:

```
failoverConfig = {
                'user': 'failover_user',\
                'password': 'failover_password',\
                'host': 'failover_host',\
                }

config = {
        'user': 'testeng',\
        'password': 'testeng',\
        'host': 'adb',\
        'failover': [failover_config],\
        }
```